# Prove $\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx=a\int_a^cf(x)dx + b\int_c^bf(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

$f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continous. Show that existe c in $[a,b]$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx=a\int_a^cf(x)dx + b\int_c^bf(x)dx.$$

I already tried integration by parts, and mean value theorem for integrals... I need a light

Comment: If you find $c\in (a,b)$ such that $\int_a^b\int_c^xf(t)\,dt\,dx = 0$ (which is possible), then with $F(x) = \int_c^xf(t)\,dt$ you have$$\int_a^bxf(x)\,dx = [xF(x)]_a^b - \int_a^bF(x)\,dx = bF(b)-aF(a) = b\int_c^bf(x)\,dx + a\int_a^cf(x)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

One can proceed as in [Prove for continous function $f$, $\int_0^1 xf (x) dx = \int_c^1 f (x) dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100997/prove-for-continous-function-f-int-01-xf-x-dx-int-c1-f-x-dx), where the case $[a,b]=[0, 1]$ is handled.

Define $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ and integrate by parts:
$$
\int_a^b xf(x) \,dx = xF(x) \bigr]_a^b - \int_a^b F(x) \, dx = bF(b) - \int_a^b F(x) \, dx\, .
$$
From the [mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals) we have $\int_a^b F(x) \, dx = (b-a)F(c)$ for some $c \in [a, b]$. It follows that
$$
\int_a^b xf(x) \,dx =  bF(b) - (b-a)F(c) = a F(c) + b(F(b)-F(c)) \\
= a \int_a^c f(x) \, dx + b\int_c^b f(x) \, dx \, .
$$